# How to create JCheckBox that changes the text in JLabel

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox, itemlistener

How can I declare `JCheckBox` so that when it's checked it will change the `JLabel` text to uppercase?

I've been trying many things yet nothing works

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    Font f = null;

    if(Bold.isSelected() && Italic.isSelected())
        f = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD + Font.ITALIC, 14);
    else if(Bold.isSelected())
        f = new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14);
    else if(Italic.isSelected())
        f = new Font("Serif", Font.ITALIC, 14);
    if(Capitalized.isSelected()){

    }


    label3.setFont(f);
}
```

What should  put inside `if(Capitalized.isSelected())`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried getting the text, then calling toUpperCase() on it:

```
label3.setText(label3.getText().toUpperCase());
```